# Como evitar que um registro quando editado salve em duplicidade?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, asp.net

Este trecho de código salva os temas de um registro. Porém, quando edito um registro, adicionando um novo cliente, o último tema desse registro duplica. Ou seja, toda vez que eu editar um registro ele duplica o tema desse registro. No exemplo abaixo eu cliquei em editar, porém não fiz nenhuma edição, apenas salvei sem alterações.

Essa é a tela de edição

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa a tela dos temas: Veja que na segunda imagem ele duplicou o tema dos cliente que tinha no registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
for (int j = 0; j < dadosTela.listaIdCliente.Count(); j++) {
  //salvar os tema se o cliente não tem
  using(var conexao3 = new ferbaEntities()) {
    int ClienteId = dadosTela.listaIdCliente[j];
    var tbTemasTela = conexao3.tbTema.Where(x => x.FgApagado == 0 && x.FgAtivo == 1 && x.IdCliente == ClienteId && x.IdTema == dadosTela.tema.IdTema).OrderBy(x => x.DsTema).ToList();
    if (tbTemasTela.Count() == 0) {
      var tbNewTemasTela = conexao3.tbTema.Where(x => x.FgApagado == 0 && x.FgAtivo == 1 && x.IdTema == dadosTela.tema.IdTema).OrderBy(x => x.DsTema).ToList();

      var tema = new tbTema();
      tema.DsTema = tbNewTemasTela[0].DsTema;
      tema.DsRGB = tbNewTemasTela[0].DsRGB;
      tema.IdCor = tbNewTemasTela[0].IdCor;
      tema.IdCliente = dadosTela.listaIdCliente[j];
      tema.FgApagado = 0;
      tema.FgAtivo = 1;

      conexao3.tbTema.Add(tema);
      conexao3.SaveChanges();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Difícil analisar o erro apenas com esse código.

O seu tema está duplicando quando você edita ou adiciona um cliente?

Certifique-se de que ao dizer o tema do cliente,
você está deixando o entity framework fazer o mapeamento dele.
Por exemplo :

```
            var TemaEscolhidoPeloCliente = "Tema";

            Cliente.Tema = _context.Temas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TemaNome == TemaEscolhidoPeloCliente);

            _context.Update(Cliente);
            _context.SaveChanges();
```

Outra coisa, sua classe Tema possui um identificador?

```
            [Key]
            public string TemaNome { get; set; }
```

Dessa forma o entityFramework não irá permitir um registro duplicado e você será obrigado a fazer uma verificação de existência antes.

```
            if(_context.Temas.Any(x => x.TemaNome == TemaEscolhidoPeloCliente))
            {
                //Existe esse tema
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Add(Tema);
                _Context.SaveChanges();
            }
```